# Time problem on List Object for DateTime Column

Tags: c#, oracle, list

The Datetime column from the Oracle database returns the rows as expected. However when i use list, time shows always `12:00 AM`

I am trying to solve this about 3 days but no luck. What could be the reason?

```
public class list_TA
    {
        public DateTime SAMPLE_TIME { get; set; }


        public list_TA(DateTime SAMPLE_TIME)
        {
            this.SAMPLE_TIME = SAMPLE_TIME;

        }
    }

//Getting the results 
using (OracleConnection conperf = new OracleConnection(oradb))
    {
        conperf.Open();
        listTA = conperf.Query<list_TA>("select SAMPLE_TIME from customer").ToList();
        conperf.Close();
    }

// Output from Database is actually like this
20-JUN-20 10:26:15
20-JUN-20 10:26:30
20-JUN-20 10:26:45

// However listTA values returns time always 12:00 AM
20-JUN-20 12:00:00 AM
20-JUN-20 12:00:00 AM
20-JUN-20 12:00:00 AM
```

Comment: I don't understand how the SQL command is bound to list_TA type. You're selecting only one column in the SQL statement. I assume the Oracle engine isn't able to map your records to list_TA objects because of different reasons (column type or time format for example) hence SAMPLE_TIME gets its default value in terms of time (12 AM). You'll need to debug more and add more details about your customer table structure. Also, I'm not able to find the Query method as member of OracleConnection class in Microsoft docs. Are you using a 3rd party Oracle wrapper?

Comment: well,i am using odp.net

Comment: Did you crosscheck the datatype of *SAMPLE_TIME* in Oracle? And how did you check values in `list_TA`?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found that it is all about odp.net nls parameters. Following code solved my problem.

```
            OracleGlobalization info = conperf.GetSessionInfo();
            info.DateFormat = "DD-MM-YYYY hh24:mi:ss";
            conperf.SetSessionInfo(info);
```